# If else ladder in Spring and Hibernate using JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm trying to implement the filter in two fields i.e. category and itemBrand by using Spring, Hibernate and JSP. The scenario is if I pass category then it will return the records of that category or if I pass the itemBrand the it will return the records of that itemBrand and if I pass both category and itemBrand then it will return the records in combination of both and if I pass nothing that means both the fields (category and itemBrand) are empty the it will return all the record from that table.
But I'm getting the below while implementing it.
Can anyone help me out for this ?

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : category

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : category
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : category
    org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:486)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104)
    grocery.stock.managment.dao.AdminDaoImpl.searchByCategory(AdminDaoImpl.java:148)
    grocery.stock.managment.services.AdminServiceImpl.searchByCategory(AdminServiceImpl.java:125)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.searchByCategory(Unknown Source)
    grocery.stock.managment.controller.MainController.itemFilter(MainController.java:238)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Below is the form

```
<form class="mg-b-20" action="itemFilter" method="post">

                <div class="row gutters-8">

                    <div class="col-3-xxxl col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Category"
                            name="category" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-3-xxxl col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-12 form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Brand" name="itemBrand"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-1-xxxl col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </form>
```

Below is the Main Controller's code

```
@PostMapping("itemFilter")
    public ModelAndView itemFilter(@RequestParam("category") String category,
            @RequestParam("itemBrand") String itemBrand) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("allitems");

        if (itemBrand == "") {
            List<Item> items = adminService.searchByCategory(category);
            modelAndView.addObject("items", items);
        } else if (category == "") {
            List<Item> items = adminService.searchByItemBrand(itemBrand);
            modelAndView.addObject("items", items);
        } else if (category == "" || category == null && itemBrand == "" || itemBrand == null) {
            List<Item> items = adminService.getAllItems();
            modelAndView.addObject("items", items);
        } else {
            List<Item> items = adminService.searchByCategoryAndItemBrand(category, itemBrand);
            modelAndView.addObject("items", items);
        }

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: `if (itemBrand == "") {` is not how you compare Strings in java.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace. The last line with your code is this one: `    grocery.stock.managment.dao.AdminDaoImpl.searchByCategory(AdminDaoImpl.java:148)`. Check what's there in that line.

Comment: Don't use these constructs. Instead, dynamically create a query based on available parameters. So just create a `search` method, with 2 parameters, in that method dynamically create the query (or use the `Criteria` API even better). Saves you a lot of if/else combinaties (it will go out the roof with more parameters).

Comment: @M.Deinum Or better still, Querydsl.

Comment: @ScaryWombat please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Is QueryDSL still a thing? Last time I checked the project had been dormant for quite a while? Has the community finally stepped in/up and started maintaining it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use those constructs and especially not in a controller (it belongs in the service). Instead, create a single service method that dynamically creates a query (or `Criteria` API) based on those parameters.

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class AdminService {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public List<Item> search(String category, String itemBrand) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<item> cq = cb.createQuery(Item.class);
    Root<Item> c = cq.from(Item.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(category) {
      predicates.add(cb.equals(c.get("category", category)));
    }

    if (StringUtils.hasText(itemBrand) {
      predicates.add(cb.equals(c.get("itemBrand", itemBrand)));
    }
    cq = cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]{});
    return em.getCriteriaQuery(cq).getResultLlist();
  }

}
```

Something along these lines will do the trick (from the top of my head, so it might need some work). Adding an additional criteria is now a simple matter of checking for a value and add it to the list.

When generating a JPA metamodel you could even make it less error-prone by replacing the `c.get("category")` etc. with safer constructs.